# SMTP server with python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to send an email to my webmail(yahoo) using python3 but I have some problems with the object. I've tried with [different ports](https://kinsta.com/es/blog/configuracion-smtp-de-yahoo/)(465/587) without any success:

```
import smtplib

pass='letmein'
sender = 'manolo@yahoo.es'
receivers = ['raul@yahoo.es']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465) ### 587)
   smtpObj.set_debuglevel(1)
   smtpObj.login(sender, pass)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
   print("Error: unable to send email")
```

And this is the error I get:

send: 'ehlo [192.168.0.15]\r\n'
reply: b'250-kubenode501.mail-prod1.omega.ir2.yahoo.com Hello [192.168.0.15] [81.61.24.111])\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 41697280\r\n'
reply: b'250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'kubenode501.mail-prod1.omega.ir2.yahoo.com Hello [192.168.0.15] [81.61.24.111])\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nSIZE 41697280\nAUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER'
send: 'AUTH PLAIN AGF1c3RyYWxiaXRAeWFob28uZXMAQWFsaWNpYTAy\r\n'
reply: b'535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.\r\n'
reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.'
send: 'AUTH LOGIN YXVzdHJhbGJpdEB5YWhvby5lcw==\r\n'
Error: unable to send email

Any idea about how to fix this error?

Comment: What error? You have to be more specific.

Comment: Edit your question and add this error message to the question body, don't use comments for important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to fix:

1. Use `smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465)` because port *465* expects connection using SSL.
2. Add `smtpObj.set_debuglevel(1)` to have better help with debugging - this will tell you that you need to login first.
3. Use `smtpObj.login("login", "password")` before trying to send an email.
4. The *From* email should be the same as the login.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @mx(), I´ve followed your instructions but II still getting errors:

Comment: **Too many bad auth attempts.** you are temporally? blocked because you sent too many wrong requests. Make sure you have good login and password and try after some time.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @mx0, finally i've been able to do login¡¡¡, but now I get this new error **reply: '550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable\r\n'** What can I do to solve it??

Comment: Try to google `yahoo 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable` read some troubleshoot guide and check if you are not making any simple mistake